# Duplicate wallet address for same seed phrase

Tags: solana, wallet

Hello the STEPN App issued me with an account and wallet on the Solana network on downloading the app in March this year. The account was compromised about 11 days ago but not the wallet. I re-installed the app and was issued a new address with wallet BUT WITH THE SAME SEED PHRASE. How do I access the first wallet if it has the same seed phrase?

I contacted the STEPN team with the problem and they told me to contact Solana support as the wallet is on the Solana network.

Answer (score 1):

The same seed phrase can be used to derive multiple private keys. In order to derive the same private key you need to use the same seed phrase and the same derivation path. Step's development team should be able to tell you which derivation path they used in their previous app.

You can independently try a few common paths:

BIP-39 `solana-keygen recover`

BIP-44 `solana-keygen recover 'prompt:?key=0/0'`

The solana cookbook has more details:
https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-restore-a-keypair-from-a-mnemonic-phrase